# Refresh view after popup is dismissed in swift

Tags: ios, swift2, popup

I was watching this tutorial [youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FgCIRMz_3dE) and I have added button in popup. Button is adding coins (IAP), but the problem is when I dismiss popup it will not refresh view to see update coins. If I hit back button and then come again it is updated.

so the question is how to refresh parent view after pressing close button.

here is popupVC

```
import UIKit

class PopUpViewController: UIViewController {

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.blackColor().colorWithAlphaComponent(0.8)

    self.showAnimate()

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@IBAction func closePopUp(sender: AnyObject) {
    self.removeAnimate()
    //HERE SHOULD BE CODE TO RELOAD PARENT VIEWCONTROLER
}

func showAnimate()
{
    self.view.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1.3, 1.3)
    self.view.alpha = 0.0;
    UIView.animateWithDuration(0.25, animations: {
        self.view.alpha = 1.0
        self.view.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1.0, 1.0)
    });
}

func removeAnimate()
{
    UIView.animateWithDuration(0.25, animations: {
        self.view.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1.3, 1.3)
        self.view.alpha = 0.0;
        }, completion:{(finished : Bool)  in
            if (finished)
            {
                self.view.removeFromSuperview()
            }
    });



@IBAction func btnAddCoins(sender: UIButton) {


    for product in list {
        let prodID = product.productIdentifier
        if(prodID == "XXXX") {
            p = product
            buyProduct()
            break;
        }
    }
}
}
```

I didnt copy all IAP code.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An easy way to do this would be use a delegate to handle this. The idea would be that when you've created your `PopUpViewController` you will assign the delegate to it. This implies that the parent VC conforms to the delegate.

An example of what the delegate could be is here. Note that it would be advisable to support a means to handle success, failure, and cancellation.

None of this code is tested for compilation and is only for reference.

```
protocol IAPDelegate {
    func purchaseSuccessful()
    func purchaseCancelled()
    func purchaseFailed()
}
```

Your class would change to something like this. I am omitting a bunch of your code. You would also need to figure out where to handle `purchaseCancelled` and `purchaseFailed`. Additionally, you may want to supply further information (i.e arguments) to the calls, but I leave that up to you to figure out.

```
class PopUpViewController: UIViewController {
    weak var iapDelegate : IAPDelegate?

    // Your other code here
    @IBAction func closePopUp(sender: AnyObject) {
        self.removeAnimate()
        iapDelegate?.purchaseSuccessful()
    }
}
```

Your parent VC, which I am calling here `ParentViewController` would be something like

```
class ParentViewController: UIViewController, IAPDelegate
```

BTW, You should think of better class naming. If `PopUpViewController` is really your IAP purchase VC, then name it as such. What happens if you want another popup view controller? What are you going to name that?